# How to check where array exist length in flatlist reactnative

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to check where data array exist in flatlist loop,

example

```js
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>{item.name}<Text>
        <Text>i Want to show this Text only in array 2,4,6,8,...<Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);

<FlatList
    data={product}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    ListEmptyComponent={(<EmptyData />)}
    style={{ flex: 1, marginBottom: 50 }}
/>
```

I need to show the text but only in array length 2,4,6,8,..., I already try use product[2] but the text shows every loop

Comment: If you want to show products length then you can pass it like `product.length` in your `<Text>` component.

Comment: i know that, but i already try product.length == 2 && <Text>Show<Text> but the text not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the text to render when the length of `product` is even. For that you can use the following code:

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>{item.name}<Text>
        {(product.length % 2) === 0 && <Text>i Want to show this Text only in array 2,4,6,8,...<Text>}
    </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

[Read more about the remainder `%` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder)